# Reading a text file with delimiters

Tags: c++

I have a text file, the contents are

```
Point1, [5, 6]
Line2, [1, 2, 3], [-5, 55, 33]
Point2, [5, 3, 1]
Line1, [1, 2], [5, 7]
```

I will do comparisions, like the first variable (Point1, Line2, Point2, Line1)

If it is point1, it will be stored into point 1 array, and 5 being set as x, and y being set as 6.

How do I set the delimter to commas and also the '[' and ']'. I just need the variable Point1, 5 and 6 to store them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem the simplest way possible - read the file using getline and then replace all the occurances of `,`, `[` and `]` with spaces. Then you can read all the input using `std::istringstream` from `<sstream>`. You could also use regular expressions(if you use boost or c++-11), but I believe what I suggest should do the job.

EDIT: here is an example how to do what I suggest. I will only show you how to input points, to handle lines as well you will have to add an if statement based on name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string line;

  while (getline(cin, line)) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
      if (line[i] == '[' || line[i] == ']' || line[i] == ',') {
        line[i] = ' ';
      }
    }
    istringstream in(line);

    string name;
    double x,y;
    in >> name >> x >> y; // Point1 <x> <y>
    ... do something with the point...
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Also you can use `replace_if` from `<algorithm>` to replace the symbols, but I decided it will be easier for you to understand this solution.

Comment: any website that I can refer to ? Need some examples

Comment: I will add an example to my answer

Comment: `code` ifstream myfile("messy.txt");
 if (myfile.is_open())
 {
  while (myfile.good())
  {
   string line;
   while (getline(cin, line)) 
   {
       for (unsigned i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) 
    {
        if (line[i] == '[' || line[i] == ']' || line[i] == ',') 
     {
            line[i] = ' ';
             }
     
        istringstream in(line);

       string name;
       double x,y;
        in >> name >> x >> y; 
     cout <<name;
      }  
   }
   return 0;
  }
  myfile.close();
 }
 else cout<< "Unable to open file";
 return 0;

Comment: how do i make it into readable code like but.. @izomorphius, did is what I did and I cout << name. nothing came out.. it was blank

Comment: When i did getline(myfile, line) , i could cout << line. but how does cin,line works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use json-cpp library. It has similar syntax:

```
{
 "Point1" : [5, 6],
 "Line2": {
     "param1" : [1, 2, 3],
     "param2" : [-5, 55, 33]
    },
  "Point2" : [5, 3, 1],
  "Line1" : {
   "param1" : [1, 2],
   "param2" : [5, 7]
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently dealing with C++. Using Quincy 2005